# Refresh ListView after update Child Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this on Firebase:
[Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60uFZ.png)

And some other foods under with the same structure. I Just created this Aaaa to make tests.

The fact is that I can list in `listview` all this foods and when I `longclick` any item It opens an `AlertDialog` that I can edit or delete any item (when add/deleted the `listview` is updated). But after editing "base", "carboidrato" and etc, when I select the item, the old value is still displayed.

I tried with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in ALL places but no success. In log and in Firebase I can see the child is updated.

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Alimentos alimento = list.get(position);
                showUpdateDeleteDialog(alimento);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

```
 private void showUpdateDeleteDialog(final Alimentos alimento) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater2 = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder2.setView(dialogView2);

        buttonDelete = (Button) dialogView2.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
        buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView2.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);

buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

 updateAlimento(alimento);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                b.dismiss();
            }

        });
```

```
private boolean updateAlimento(final Alimentos alimento) {

        final DatabaseReference dU = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("alimentos").child(String.valueOf(alimento));


        dU.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {


                    nome = snapshot.getKey();

                    dU.child("base").setValue(base);
                    dU.child("calcio").setValue(calcio);
                    dU.child("carboidrato").setValue(carbo);
                    dU.child("cinzas").setValue(cinzas);
                    dU.child("cobre").setValue(cobre);
                    dU.child("colesterol").setValue(colesterol);
                    dU.child("energiaKJ").setValue(kcalkj);
                    dU.child("energiaKcal").setValue(kcal);
                    dU.child("ferro").setValue(ferro);
                    dU.child("fibraAlimentar").setValue(fibra);
                    dU.child("fosforo").setValue(fosforo);
                    dU.child("lipideos").setValue(lip);
                    dU.child("magnesio").setValue(magnesio);
                    dU.child("manganes").setValue(manganes);
                    dU.child("niacina").setValue(niacina);
                    dU.child("piridoxina").setValue(piridoxina);
                    dU.child("potassio").setValue(potassio);
                    dU.child("proteina").setValue(prot);
                    dU.child("rae").setValue(rae);
                    dU.child("re").setValue(re);
                    dU.child("retinol").setValue(retinol);
                    dU.child("riboflavina").setValue(riboflavina);
                    dU.child("sodio").setValue(sodio);
                    dU.child("tiamina").setValue(tiamina);
                    dU.child("umidade").setValue(umidade);
                    dU.child("vitaminaC").setValue(vit);
                    dU.child("zinco").setValue(zinco);

                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        dU.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                Long changedPost = snapshot.getValue(long.class);


                System.out.println("The updated post title is: " + changedPost);

                Log.i("TAGBase", String.valueOf(snapshot.getValue(long.class)));

                
                listview.invalidateViews();

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }



        });


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), alimento + " atualizado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, when you edit "base", "carboidrato" .. does `onChildChanged()` is called ?

Comment: Yes. I checked now with Debug. When I edit, it displays the new value in snapshot.

Comment: Cool .. noticed that in `onChildChanged`, you didn't update anything with `changedPost`, and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.. please make sure you really update the list of the adapter

Comment: @Zain I Just created this changedPost to check if It is really getting the update. I already tried to create a New list, but then my old list is erased and only the edited food is displayed. Can you give me a hint what can I do? Just remember that this info of "base", "carboidrato" is displayed inside a AlertBuilder.